# Como retomar todos os alunos com nome em comum

Tags: c, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados

Estou a desenvolver um programa que tem de gerir uma cantina de uma escola e sobre o menu tenho uma opção para pesquisar aluno por número e outra para pesquisar todos os alunos que têm o primeiro nome em comum. Eis o meu codigo, onde não consigo ver o meu problema:

```
void FindStudentsByName(FILE *f) {  
     //FILE *file;  
     //const char *filename = "database-aluno.txt";     
     //file = fopen(filename,"r"); 
     struct Aluno student;  
     char name[50];     
     printf("Insira Nome (Primeiro nome) ");    
     scanf("%s", name);     
     while (!(feof(f)))     
     {      
        fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %lf %d-%d\n", &student.num, student.name,
 student.fname,&student.saldo, &student.dia, &student.mes);

        if (name == student.name)       
        {           
            fprintf(f,"Numero: %d \n", student.num);
            fprintf(f,"Nome: %s\n ", student.fname);        
        }   
     }
 }
```

Quase tenho certeza que o erro é pequeno, mas não consegui resolver. O output que pretendo é se por exemplo existirem 20 alunos com o nome vitor o programa apresente-me os números dos 20 alunos e os nomes dos mesmos.

Comment: o seu `database-aluno.txt` tem que formato?

Comment: Como assim formato do ficheiro ??

Comment: É um exemplo do conteudo, você usa quebra de linha ou um formato tipo arquivos de *csv*?

Comment: Quebra de linha, na verdade 1 aluno corresponde a uma Linha

Comment: Outra coisa, você tem que posta a estrutura de `struct Aluno student;` por que não é possivel entender como funciona o código. Amigo por favor leia este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Na verdade no inicio do programa tenho uma estrutura chamada aluno com as variaveis indicadas em fscanf

Comment: Mesmo a chamar a estrutura por exemplo Aluno[acstruct].name onde acstruct, tipo int é uma "variavel para acompanhar a esttutura", o programa nao me da o output pretendido

Comment: Siga as instruções do link que lhe passei por favor, assim você conseguirá mais respostas provavelmente, é dificil conseguir respostas quando as pessoas tem que deduzir como funciona um código que só tem um pedaço. Espero que entenda. Até mais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu primeiro problema está aqui:

```c
if (name == student.name)
```

Isso daí vai verificar se os dois ponteiros estão apontando para o mesmo endereço de memória, o que nunca vai acontecer.

O que você queria é comparar se as strings são iguais:

```c
if (strcmp(name, student.name) == 0)
```

Há um outro problema também, você parece que abre o arquivo para leitura (embora esteja comentado):

```c
//file = fopen(filename,"r");
```

Mas tenta escrever nele (mas você abriu para leitura, e não escrita):

```c
fprintf(f,"Numero: %d \n", student.num);
fprintf(f,"Nome: %s\n ", student.fname);
```

Além disso, dado o nome da função `FindStudentsByName`, não faz muito sentido você querer escrever no arquivo para procurar alguma coisa, não acha?

Também, a sua função de **busca de alunos** não retorna nada (e nem preenche algum conteúdo de memória de algum ponteiro dado). Assim fica difícil usar ela para fazer algum trabalho útil, não acha?

Finalmente, se você quiser retornar **todos** os alunos com o nome em comum, vai precisar montar uma lista ou array de alunos, né?

Talvez o que você queria é isso:

```c
int FindStudentsByName(FILE *f, struct Aluno **array, int max) {  
    char name[50];
    int indice = 0;
    struct Aluno student;
    printf("Insira Nome (Primeiro nome) ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    while (!(feof(f)) && indice < max)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%s %s %s %lf %d-%d\n", &student.num, student.name,
                student.fname, &student.saldo, &student.dia, &student.mes);

        if (strcmp(name, student.name) == 0)
        {
            array[indice]->num = student.num;
            strcpy(array[indice]->name, student.name);
            strcpy(array[indice]->fname, student.fname);
            array[indice]->saldo = student.saldo;
            array[indice]->dia = student.dia;
            array[indice]->mes = student.mes;
            indice++;
        }
    }
    return indice;
}
```